# Yii: Render Partial and Return to AJAX in JSON format

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, renderpartial

As per subject above, I have some confusion on the return of the data. So, when I try to return the render partial view data from my controller to AJAX the code will be as follows.

JQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('ajaxrequest');?>",
         type: "POST",
         data: {affordableCarPrice: ccarprice},                        
         success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
         }
});
```

Yii Controller

```
public function actionAjaxrequest(){               

        $carListingView[] = $this->renderPartial("_budgetNewCarsListing", array('newCarListing' => $newCarListing), true);
        $carListingView[] = $this->renderPartial("_budgetUsedCarsListing", array('usedCarListing' => $usedCarListing), true);

        var_dump($carListingView);
}
```

The codes inside the controller, I had minimize it and when I log the return data, it gives me the correct one. But, when I use json_encode the array in the controller, and I go back see the return data, it gives me the wrong one.

Despite I set dataType: 'json' and contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", in the JQuery ajax. Or header('Content-type: application/json'); in the controller. It still returns the wrong data.

Need help on this very badly, as I couldn't resolve this problem for like almost 2 days. :(

Comment: you go back via "back" button on the browser ?

Comment: It is an AJAX callback dude, it suppose to return the HTML code that render the views and keep them in an array in order for me to encode them into JSON and pass back to the AJAX callback data.

Answer (score 8):

To return the data to the JS:

```
public function actionAjaxrequest(){               
    $carListingView[] = $this->renderPartial("_budgetNewCarsListing", array('newCarListing' => $newCarListing), true);
    $carListingView[] = $this->renderPartial("_budgetUsedCarsListing", array('usedCarListing' => $usedCarListing), true);

    echo CJSON::encode($carListingView);
}
```

Two important things.  The first is is the third argument to `renderPartial()`.  As the [doc states](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail):

> whether the rendering result should be returned instead of being
>   displayed to end users

This means instead of echo'ing out the rendered view, it'll be returned as a string.

The second is the [CJSON::encode()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON#encode-detail), which takes the variable and converts it to a JSON representation, which javascript will be able to handle.  `CJSON::encode()`'s advantages are that it doesn't require any particular version of PHP (`json_encode` requires PHP 5.2 or newer), and that it can handle Active Records.

Comment: dude, the results when I got it back in JavaScript is not the results I want :O

Comment: Thank you ernie! I just came accross the same question. Please update your answer to point out the last `true` is essential as one might not see it. It's "hidden" by the horizontal scrollbar